# HTTP request on hosted PHP files

Tags: php, http, authentication, react-native, cpanel

I'm currently making an app with `React Native` and I need to perform some HTTP requests on PHP files, that are hosted on a CPanel file manager.

So I need to put the link in my request, but the problem is that it includes a security token when I sign-in on the website to see these files.

As it is changing every time, I guess that I need to get this token in my app and use it to perform the requests.

I browsed the documentation of CPanel to find a way but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Why don't you point a domain to that hosting to request by domain, instead of using the impossible solution? (by hosting IP with your token)

Comment: I'm not proficient at all in PHP, I don't understand what you say.

Comment: See my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method without domain-pointing is access by hosting IP and your username account on that hosting. Example:

```
http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/~username/yourapifile.php
```

where XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is your hosting IP and username is your username account (with **~** prefix).

Comment: When I try it with the username, I get a 401 Invalid security token error.

Comment: I found the "shared IP address" on CPanel but I can't access the folders inside. I'm searching for it.

Comment: Yeah it is. The thing is that there is a .htaccess inside. Is it because of it that I can't access it? (my permissions are on 455).